# {PKG_NAME}_generate_messages_cpp vs {PKG_NAME}_gencpp

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, using catkin in groovy I have seen two ways to specify dependencies to build msgs and srvs:

```
add_dependencies(my_bin {PKG_NAME}_generate_messages_cpp)
```

and

```
add_dependencies(my_bin {PKG_NAME}_gencpp)
```

Which one is correct?
None of them though seem to build services that my_bin depends on.

D.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60994/%7Bpkg_name%7D_generate_messages_cpp-vs-%7Bpkg_name%7D_gencpp/) by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1420 on 2013-04-17

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both of those lines are correct for now, but the latter will be deprecated.

The `_gencpp` is the old style, the `_generate_messages_cpp` target is the new name (more descriptive).

These targets are created by the `generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)` CMake macro call. Calling `add_dependencies(my_bin ${PKG_NAME}_generate_messages_cpp)` just tells CMake that the `${PKG_NAME}_generate_messages_cpp` target should be built before the `my_bin` target. It does not instruct CMake to *generate* your messages. So, if you are expecting this line to cause your services to be built, then that's incorrect.

See the ROS tutorials about how to get services generated:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Using_srv

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2013-04-19**:
William, the services that needed to be build are in the pkg PKG_NAME I depend on with the above code. And if I understand you correctly then it should be all fine.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-04-19**:
That should ensure that those services are generated before your code is built.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2013-12-03**:
As an extra bit of detail for the answer by @William, see https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/547#issuecomment-29740592 by Dirk Thomas.

**Comment by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on 2015-04-15**:
What could be the problem if the only one which works to me is `_gencpp`? With `_generate_message_cpp` it does not generate message and action files which I have included correctly...

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-04-15**:
I think my post has a typo, it should be `_generate_messages_cpp`.

**Comment by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on 2015-04-15**:
thanks! It's ok now. (I've copied the wrong one without noticing the typo)